# PHP failed to connect to Microsoft Access Database

Tags: php, database, ms-access, odbc

I am trying to connect to a Microsoft Access Database using PHP PDO,  but got this error message:

> SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

The error happens at this line:

```
 $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};Dbq=C:\\wamp\\www\\phprestsql\\UTILITY.accdb");
```

I do not have an user name setup for the database, I also tried

```
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};Dbq=C:\\wamp\\www\\phprestsql\\UTILITY.accdb;User=Admin");
```

and the problem still remains

What could be the problem? I checked the path for the Access Database file and it is correct.
I am using the WAMP for the PHP.

The system is Windows 7 Home Premium. Do I need to install some ODBC driver?

**Edit:**
I downloaded the ACE according to HansUp's suggestion, but still has the same problem.
I have also tried to convert my file to .mdb, but still has the same problem. In the PHP code I verified the ,mdb file does exist. So it must be some kind of environment issue.

**Update**
Forgot to mention that I was running Virtual Box on Mac. Perhaps that was the problem.
Got really frustrated, then moved on to an old Windows Vista 32 bit machine and setup the environment using all 32 bit tools. It worked in the first run. 
Thanks
Ray

Comment: Check the user under which you set up ODBC connection. Also of  course spelling of Data source name.

Comment: Did you mean the user for the database? There is no user setup. And the spelling is correct, I copy pasted the whole path and file name from file explorer.

Comment: The Jet driver does not support the newer ACCDB format; you need the ACE driver.  ACE is not included with Windows.  It comes with later Office versions or download and install it separately: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 With 64 bit Windows, if PHP is also 64 bit, you need the 64 bit ACE driver.

Comment: Thanks HansUp. I downloaded the ACE but still get the same error. I tried to set up File DSN through the Data Source but still it only lists .mdb, do I need to some other configuration?

Comment: @galchen, the Windows 7, WAMP, and ACE are all 64bit.