# PHP + PDO ODBC Connection error

Tags: php, pdo

I am using PHP to connect to an MS access .accdb using the following connection

```php
try {
    $conn = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,
    *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\seedOnline\\db\\seed12c.accdb;Pwd=");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {     //if connection fails
    echo 'Seed Database Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

This program works on two different computers with Xampp and Apache in our office, but when copying the entire program to new computers it failswith the following error:

```
Seed Database Connection failed: SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 
0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Here is line 34:

```
foreach ($conn->query($qryUsers) as $qryUsersRow) {
```

The query $qryUsers is :

```
$qryUsers = "SELECT * FROM tblPwd";
```

and the table does exist.

Any particular configuration that I may be missing? All machines are windows 8.1 64 bit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795496/php-failed-to-connect-to-microsoft-access-database

Comment: I did everything on that link, and still have the same issue.

Comment: another link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841948/pdo-odbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified